# How to get the generic type of class in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I need to try and get the generic type passed into a class in TypeScript.

See my example below, I initialize my class with type `'hello' | 'goodbye'`

I then want to create a function with has the parameter of the type passed into the original class.

Is this possible?

```
class MyTestClass<T> {
  doSomething = (myType: T, count: number) => {
    // ...
  }
}

const myTest = new MyTestClass<'hello' | 'goodbye'>()

const myNewMethod = (subType: typeof myTest) => {
  // I want subType to be 'hello' | 'goodbye'
}
```

Comment: ```type instanceType = typeof myTest extends MyTestClass<infer U> ? U : never;```

Comment: Thank you that is exactly what I need, if you want to add as answer I will mark as complete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditional types wit the `infer` keyword to extract the `U` from `MyTestClass<U>`

```
type subType = typeof mytest extends MyTestClass<infer U> ? U : never;
```

Here, if `myTest` is any kind of `MyTestClass<X>`, then `subType` will be the `X`, otherwise it will be `never` (which won't ever happen since your `myTest` is explicitly a `MyTestClass`.